# brush lag, freeze errors

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, 2d, brushes

no matter which version of the blender programme I use, I encounter stuttering and delay errors. especially when working in 2d, the brush tool starts to delay after 3-4 minutes of use. I have installed many lts versions but the error still persists. Likewise, when doing 3d modelling, it starts to slow down after a few minutes of use in the same way, although it is later and less stuttering than 2d animation. in other programs 3d 2d vector etc. I can use it without stuttering, but it surprises me that there are stuttering in blender. please help

device specifications
Processor 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz 2.80GHz
memory 512 gb
Graphics card: intel(R) iris(R) Xe graphics
Installed RAM 16.0 GB (available: 15.8 GB)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch Pen and touch support with 10 touch points